# How to render polygons of arbitrary shape?

Tags: 2d, rendering

I am trying to render a plane with nodes.

FYI : Nodes know what other nodes it is being attached to.

I can think of a way to render them as long as they are aligned in a circular pattern; have a center and draw triangles. However I want the shape to be not necessarily circular.

I have a picture below to enhance my description. Attempting to draw such a vertices with my previously stated method will result into an undesired shape, like the third picture.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

If you take the points A,B,C and derive the vectors AB and BC you will find that:

```
atan2(AB.x,AB.y) - atan2(BC.x,BC.y) < 0
```

Conversely if you take the points B,C,D and derive the vectors BC and CD you will find that:

```
atan2(BC.x,BC.y) - atan2(CD.x,CD.y) > 0
```

By using this test you can identify which points define concave or convex angles.